git bundle create with variable
how to create git bundle from ci in runner between previous and last tag?
I need create git bundle on ci but not work.
My stage is:
create-bundle:
  stage: bundling
  variables:
    BU_FILE_NAME: 'last.bundle'
    BU_FILE_PATH: 'D:\BU\ProjectName'
  before_script:
    - $PREVIOUS_VERSION = $(git describe --abbrev=0 --tags (git rev-list --tags --skip=1 --max-count=1))
    - $LAST_VERSION = $(git describe --abbrev=0 --tags (git rev-list --tags --max-count=1))
  script:
    - echo "Start @@@@@@@@@ create-bundle"
    - cd $BETA_PATH
    - echo $PREVIOUS_VERSION
    - echo $LAST_VERSION
    - git bundle create $BU_FILE_NAME $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH $PREVIOUS_VERSION..$LAST_VERSION 
    - mv -Force $BU_FILE_NAME $BU_FILE_PATH
    - git status
  only:
    - Dev

and this line not work correctly:
git bundle create $BU_FILE_NAME $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH $PREVIOUS_VERSION..$LAST_VERSION

after many try I find this work:
git bundle create $BU_FILE_NAME $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH 1.1.7..$LAST_VERSION

how to solve it?

That's not how you set shell variables!
Change the before_script lines to:
    - PREVIOUS_VERSION=$(git describe --abbrev=0 --tags "$(git rev-list --tags --skip=1 --max-count=1)")
    - LAST_VERSION=$(git describe --abbrev=0 --tags "$(git rev-list --tags --max-count=1)")

Further explanation
Take the shell line you had written:
$PREVIOUS_VERSION = $(git describe --abbrev=0 --tags (git rev-list --tags --skip=1 --max-count=1))

On the first pass, the shell interpreter expands $ expressions, so let's do that:
 = $(git describe --abbrev=0 --tags (git rev-list --tags --skip=1 --max-count=1))

Oops! Since $PREVIOUS_VERSION expands to nothing, it disappears from our shell line and causes a syntax error.
For now, let's fix that:
PREVIOUS_VERSION = $(git describe --abbrev=0 --tags (git rev-list --tags --skip=1 --max-count=1))

Spaces in shell are important too! Variables are set using name=value syntax, and never should there be any whitespace surrounding your =.
Second fix:
PREVIOUS_VERSION=$(git describe --abbrev=0 --tags (git rev-list --tags --skip=1 --max-count=1))

What this does is evaluate the subshell ($(cmd; cmd; etc.)) and set a variable named PREVIOUS_VERSION in the local shell environment.
However, there's a problem with your subshell; It's set to run git describe --abbrev=0 --tags (git rev-list --tags --skip=1 --max-count=1) which is a syntax error.
You fix that by nesting the subshells:
PREVIOUS_VERSION=$(git describe --abbrev=0 --tags $(git rev-list --tags --skip=1 --max-count=1))

I then added the quotes for string safety. If $(git rev-list --tags --skip=1 --max-count=1) expanded to something with spaces, it would break on whitespace and give the outer subshell more than one shell argument.
All together:
PREVIOUS_VERSION=$(git describe --abbrev=0 --tags "$(git rev-list --tags --skip=1 --max-count=1)")

